# How do I shorten the multiple IFs

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code. How can I shortern this code?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Range("B15").Value = 6 Then
        MsgBox "Maximum Beams Reached (7)", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Range("B15").Value = Range("B15").Value + 1
    Columns(colNum & "D").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("D3:D13").Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Range("D3:D13").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous

    If Range("B15").Value = 1 Then
        Range("D15").Value = "Beam Summary"
        Range("D16").Value = "  Concrete Volume"
        Range("D17").Value = "  Rebar Length"
    End If

    If Range("B15").Value = 1 Then
        Range("D3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value + 1
    Else
        If Range("B15").Value = 2 Then
            Range("D3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value
            Range("E3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value + 1
        Else
            If Range("B15").Value = 3 Then
                Range("D3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value - 1
                Range("E3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value
                Range("F3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value + 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Look up `ElseIf`, `Select Case` and/or `IIF`.  Also, you can combine both of your `Range("B15").Value = 1` into a single block, instead of having the same `If` statement twice.

Comment: One advice: Indent your code!

Comment: ^ Check out this cool [smart indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation).

Comment: Just curious.. What is the value of `colNum`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can immediately make it shorter by changing

```
If <Value>=1 Then
    Output = <Something>
Else
    If <Value>=2 Then
        Output = <Something else>
    End If
End If
```

to become

```
If <Value>=1 Then
    Output = <Something>
ElseIf <Value>=2 Then
    Output = <Something else>
End If
```

Getting more advanced, you could use a `Select Case` for the same thing:

```
Select Case <Value>
    Case 1:
        Output = <Something>
    Case 2:
        Output = <Something else>
End Select
```

Or even use `Choose`

```
Output = Choose(<value>, <something>, <something else>)
```

Here is your code sample in all three variants - others (such as `IIf`, or a formula that converts 1/2/3 into -1/0/1) are available too

```
'ElseIf
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Range("B15").Value = 6 Then
        MsgBox "Maximum Beams Reached (7)", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Range("B15").Value = Range("B15").Value + 1
    Columns(colNum & "D").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("D3:D13").Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Range("D3:D13").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous

    If Range("B15").Value = 1 Then
        Range("D15").Value = "Beam Summary"
        Range("D16").Value = "  Concrete Volume"
        Range("D17").Value = "  Rebar Length"

        Range("D3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value + 1
    ElseIf Range("B15").Value = 2 Then
        Range("D3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value
        Range("E3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value + 1
    ElseIf Range("B15").Value = 3 Then
        Range("D3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value - 1
        Range("E3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value
        Range("F3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value + 1
    End If
End Sub

'Select Case
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Range("B15").Value = 6 Then
        MsgBox "Maximum Beams Reached (7)", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Range("B15").Value = Range("B15").Value + 1
    Columns(colNum & "D").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("D3:D13").Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Range("D3:D13").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous

    Select Case Range("B15").Value
        Case 1:
            Range("D15").Value = "Beam Summary"
            Range("D16").Value = "  Concrete Volume"
            Range("D17").Value = "  Rebar Length"

            Range("D3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value + 1
        Case 2:
            Range("D3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value
            Range("E3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value + 1
        Case 3
            Range("D3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value - 1
            Range("E3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value
            Range("F3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value + 1
    End Select
End Sub

'Choose
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Range("B15").Value = 6 Then
        MsgBox "Maximum Beams Reached (7)", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Range("B15").Value = Range("B15").Value + 1
    Columns(colNum & "D").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("D3:D13").Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Range("D3:D13").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous

    If Range("B15").Value = 1 Then
            Range("D15").Value = "Beam Summary"
            Range("D16").Value = "  Concrete Volume"
            Range("D17").Value = "  Rebar Length"
    End If

    If Range("B15").Value >=1 AND Range("B15").Value <=3 Then
        Range("D3").Value = Choose(Range("B15").Value, "Beam " & Range("B15").Value + 1, "Beam " & Range("B15").Value, "Beam " & Range("B15").Value - 1)
        Range("E3").Value = Choose(Range("B15").Value, Range("E3").Value, "Beam " & Range("B15").Value + 1, "Beam " & Range("B15").Value)
        Range("F3").Value = Choose(Range("B15").Value, Range("E3").Value, Range("E3").Value, "Beam " & Range("B15").Value + 1)
    End IF
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a Select Case:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Range("B15").Value = 6 Then
        MsgBox "Maximum Beams Reached (7)", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Range("B15").Value = Range("B15").Value + 1
    Columns(colNum & "D").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("D3:D13").Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Range("D3:D13").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Select Case Range("b15").Value
        Case 1
            Range("D15").Value = "Beam Summary"
            Range("D16").Value = "  Concrete Volume"
            Range("D17").Value = "  Rebar Length"
            Range("D3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value + 1
        Case 2
            Range("D3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value
            Range("E3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value + 1
        Case 3
            Range("D3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value - 1
            Range("E3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value
            Range("F3").Value = "Beam " & Range("B15").Value + 1
    End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could do that easier without an if-statement (at least if I got the purpose right)

```
Dim nBeams As Integer, i As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    nBeams = sht.Range("B15").Value

    ...

    For i = 1 To nBeams
        sht.Cells(3, 3 + (i-1)) = "Beam " & i
    Next i

    ...

    Set sht = Nothing
```